# java.lang.RuntimeException from Adobe AIR app

Tags: android, air, kindle-fire

I have an app on Amazon that sometimes (less than 1% of installations) crashes, which is reflected in Crash Reports. Obviously, I don't have access to the actual devices where the app crashed. Below is one of the crash reports. Can anything be done to identify the cause of the crashes?

java.lang.RuntimeException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2690)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:964)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at android.app.Activity.missingDialog(Activity.java:2636)
    at android.app.Activity.dismissDialog(Activity.java:2621)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.Prompt.dismissDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.Prompt.dismiss(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptManagerImpl.finish(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptManagerImpl.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.i.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.n.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.n.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.context.d.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.framework.context.d.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.android.Kiwi.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
    at air.com.sierravistasoftware.SightWordsSB1.AppEntry.onDestroy(AppEntry.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
    ... 11 more

Comment: do you know which Kindle devices it's happening on (Gingerbread or ICS) and which version of the AIR runtime (are you using the platform's own version, or bundling it as a captive runtime)?

Comment: Gingerbread (version 2.3.4). AIR 3.5 as a captive runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems dismissing a dialog. Maybe the problem comes when the dialog is started, the device orientation is changed and the activity is recreated without the dialog. In this case, if you try to dismiss the dialog, the app will crash.

Try replicating it to see if this is the problem.

You may prefer using DialogFragment to avoid this problem or simply catch the exception and move on, as you got what you were looking for (your dialog dismissed).

UPDATE:

Your error log states that it's trying to dismiss a missing dialog when the activity is being destroyed. It could be an issue in the `com.amazon.android.framework` source code, and maybe the users get prompted for something before the crash.

You could try to replicate situations when your Activity is destroyed.

Following our chat via the comments, I can't think in anything else without seeing the code, so I encourage you to use a bug tracking system to help you find under what conditions is your app crashing.

Try [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra):

> ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their
>   crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android
>   applications developers to help them get data from their applications
>   when they crash or behave erroneously.

Comment: I'm using Adobe AIR 3.5 as a captive runtime. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: It's just a possibility a think in, as it seems that the app crashes trying to dismiss a missing dialog. Do you dismiss a dialog anywhere? In that case, can you replicate the crash changing orientation?

Comment: I understand your theory and appreciate your suggestions, but I don't think this is the case here. 1) The app ignores orientation changes. 2) I'm not using native dialogs. Android doesn't "know" it's a dialog. It's just something in Flash display list.

Comment: Ok, but according to your error log, your app is crashing while trying to dismiss a dialog.

Comment: As a programmer, I'm sure you have seen plenty of situations when error messages are not exactly correct :)

Comment: As a programmer, I've learned to give those error logs a big importance. They may just tell you the effects but not the exact cause, but they are definitely a guide to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Maybe, there's an issue in the `com.amazon.android.framework` source code, and maybe the users get prompted for something before the crash.

Comment: That's my guess too. I wish the trace also gave me some pointers as to were to look for the cause of crash. As I mentioned in the original question, this happens on much less than 1% of installations, so it could be some weird combination of hardware and software.

Comment: You could try to replicate it. It's happening in the `onDestroy()`. An Activity is destroyed exiting the app, on screen orientation changes, on keyboard disappearing... try these type of scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't replicate that.

Comment: No more ideas without seeing the code. Maybe you should use a bug tracker system. I updated my answer.